# Javascript updatepanel problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, updatepanel

I am having a problem with a javascript code. I want to update 2 update panels with javascript.  here is the code.  The updPnlLoadPmt has 3 triggers but the 2nd updatePanel does not have any triggers.  Could that be a problem?  Thank you!

```
    function pageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {
        var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
        var loadpmtPnlID = '<%=updPnlLoadPmt.ClientID %>';
        var AdvancepmtPnlID = '<%=UpdPnlAdvances.ClientID %>';
        if (updatedPanels.length > 0) {
            if (loadpmtPnlID == updatedPanels[0].id) {
                document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalDueAmount.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=loadDueAmount.ClientID %>').value;
            } else if (AdvancepmtPnlID == updatedPanels[0].id) {
                document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalDueAmount.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=hdnadvanceDue.ClientID %>').value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW, @Lucas you might want to add the ASP.NET and ASP.NET 4 tags to your posts too. Those tags have a lot of readers. I'll go ahead and exercise my editing powers and do it for you this time!